# OBD2/CAN BUS problems with send commands

Tags: android, bluetooth, can-bus

I'm developing application (Android). This aplication is connected to OBD2 compliant vehicle /CAN BUS and  read data from it. I've done succesfully connection using OBDKey and read data using OBD message format. This message format is mode + pin

But now I have problems with CAN BUS How should I send command called message_id? What kind of  AT commands I must send?

Answer (score 2):

To specify the CAN bus, first determine which CAN bus speed you will use then the CAN bus ID length. If it is a standard OBD-II based CAN system, e.g. 11bit ID, 500 kbaud then use ATSP6 to set this protocol.
Then use ATSHxxx to set the target ID, e.g. ATSH7E0
The use ATCMxxx and ATCFxxx to set the CAN mask and filter to handle your receive frame filters.
Let me know directly if you need more specific help.